# Show textbox based on the checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a question, I have 2 checkbox, and I want to show a textbox if a checkbox have value Y, My code:

```
<label>Admin:</label>
                <div class="onoffswitch">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="is_admin" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" value="Y" id="is_admin">
                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="is_admin">
                        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <label>Verificator:</label>
                <div class="onoffswitch">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="is_verificator" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" value="Y" id="is_verificator">
                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="is_verificator">
                        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <input type="text" style="display:none;" placeholder="" id="if_checked"/><br/>
```

My jquery:

```
<script>
$("input[name=is_verificator]").change(function(){

    if($(this).val() == "Y")
    {
        $("#if_checked").show();
    }else{
        $("#if_checked").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: what problem do you have?

Comment: The textbox who have id='if_checked' doesn't display when the value of checkbox who have id='is_verificator' have value="Y"

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap jquery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` as shown :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input[name=is_verificator]").change(function(){
     if($(this).val() == "Y" && $(this).is(":checked"))  //changed this condition as per OP comment
     {
       $("#if_checked").show();
     }else{
       $("#if_checked").hide();
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Now the textbox appear when I checked the checkbox, but doesn't dissapear

Comment: @p3tos..see updated answer you haven't stated condition properly in question ... see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `.is(":checked")` function.

```
$(':checkbox[name="is_verificator"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        $("#if_checked").show();
    }else{
        $("#if_checked").hide();
    }
});
```